# visualizar pdf de aplicacion Angular 10 en Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, angular10

Hola amigos tengo desarrollada mi aplicacion en angular 10 donde tego un modulo para visualizar pdf.

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [base64Src]="pdfSrc" useBrowserLocale="true" height="500px"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

la version de esta libreria es la 6, aunque eh intentado con la 5 y la 7 y con ninguna me funciona.

cabe recalcar que para chrome y Edge si mecarga de manera correcta el pdf pero internet explorer me carga asi:

[image: IE]

Comment: En [el sitio oficial de npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) para esta librería dice que `Internet Explorer 11 is no longer supported`. También dice que `The last version known to be compatible is 5.3`. Así pues, siempre es sano comenzar por leer la documentación. Y cuando pruebes, borra el caché para recargar los js correctamente.

Comment: si esa parte de la documentacion la lei y la probe como tu dices borrando cache con esa misma version y nada, sin embargo no se si exista alguna libreria compatible ya que eh probado con varias y no funciona ninguna.

Comment: Tienes que revisar el package-lock para ver con qué versión efectiva de la librería terminas al compilar... No nos has mostrado el package.json para saber cómo estás poniendo la version y no sabemos cómo lo está resolviendo npm. Por último, en la misma documentación hay sección `Alternatives` con otra librería. Yo trataría de ver bien cómo se está compilando la app antes de probar otra cosa. El dev principal mismo dice que buscaba soportar IE11, así que algo pasa en tu entorno...